# Rails TypeError nill when render

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I dont understand, why i getting error "nil is not a symbol" on rendering result. Can you help me solve problem?

```
def location  
 // debug 
 @warps = Warp.all
 render json: @warps
end
```

[image]

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `warps` (
`warp` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`x` double NOT NULL,
`y` double NOT NULL,
`z` double NOT NULL,
`yaw` float NOT NULL,
`pitch` float NOT NULL,
`greeting` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`owner` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`world` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`created` int(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`warp`,`world`)
)

class Warp < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

UPD:

After tests i found that this bug happens because i have double primary key:

 `` PRIMARY KEY (`warp`,`world`) ``

Comment: Are you sure Warp.all returns records?

Comment: In the console do a `Warp.all.to_json` and see what happens?

Comment: @Doon i added image to topic

Comment: what do your warp model look like?  Do you have have  an attribute called type, and are not using STI?

Comment: @Doon empty model. Dont know, what is STI :<

Comment: Single Table Inheritance. Your model isn't empty. there are attributes defined I can see warp, x, y, z, yaw, pitch, greeting, owner,   Is there an attribute in there called `type`

Comment: @Doon i use exisiting table. Added table info in header.

Comment: Please post text, not images.

Comment: your table doesn't follow rails Guidelines, and that is why it is failing.  it doesn't have an id primary key, etc.

Comment: @Doon my other tables too not follow rails standarts and i have no problems with them.

Comment: if you do Warp.first.to_json, do you still get the nil error?

Comment: @Doon yes, i got same error.

Comment: not sure what is causing it. There is something inside your model/table, that the default to_json is choking on, you can try creating a custom json tempate and using that to render the warp

Comment: Wonder if it is `owner` that is conflicting since owner is set by `CollectionProxy`

Comment: @Doon tryed rename owner to player. Not helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def location  
 respond_to do |format|
 format.html # index.html.erb
 format.json  { render :json =>  @warps.to_json}
 end
end
```

Anyway make sure @warps returns results.

Comment: If i change Warp.all to Stat.all all works fine. Your solution throw undefined method `respond_to'

Comment: What is your Rails and Ruby version?

Comment: Rails version 4.0.2. I am using Rails::API gem.

Comment: Try 

`def location  
 // debug 
 @warps = Warp.all
 render json: @warps.to_a
end`

Comment: your solution not helped me